# How can I move an image element on the x-axis at keypress with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

In my Django project, I have a "sprite" which is an image element in the HTML template. I want to make a small interactive game on the page when clicked on "A" key, the image will move on the x-axis. How can I achieve that with JavaScript? I tried to change the offsetLeft value using .offsetLeft and the x position value by updating the .style attribute but couldn't manage it both ways.

contact.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'potbs/contact.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="col">
    <img src="media/images/phone.png" alt="phone" class="rounded floar-start">
    <img src="media/images/stick.png" class="rounded float-end" id="sprite" alt="..." style="margin-top:100px;">
    <img src="media/images/wasd.png"  class="rounded float-end" id="wasd" alt="..." style="margin-top:100px;display: none;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary float-end" id="start">Start</button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

contact.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    const button = document.getElementById("start");
    const wasd = document.getElementById("wasd");
    const sprite = document.getElementById("sprite");

    
    button.onclick = function(){
        button.style.display = "none";
        wasd.style.display = "block"
        document.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
            if(event.key == "a"){
                wasd.style.display = "none";
                sprite.offsetLeft = sprite.offsetLeft + 10;
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to position elements relative to a container would be to set the position for the container as `relative` and for the child as `absolute`, then use the `left` and `top` style properties to position the element as you wish. So in your case, you could do something like this -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    function limitInPercent(value) {
      if (value < 0) return 0;
      if (value > 100) return 100;
      return value;
    }
    const SCALE = 10;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

      const sprite = document.getElementById("sprite");


      document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        const top = sprite.style.top || 0;
        const left = sprite.style.left || 0;
        if (event.key == "a") {
          sprite.style.left = limitInPercent(parseInt(left) - SCALE) + "%";
        } else if (event.key == "d") {
          sprite.style.left = limitInPercent(parseInt(left) + SCALE) + "%";
        } else if (event.key == "w") {
          sprite.style.top = limitInPercent(parseInt(top) - SCALE) + "%";
        } else if (event.key == "s") {
          sprite.style.top = limitInPercent(parseInt(top) + SCALE) + "%";
        }
      });
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="sprite">x</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```